# What is my context and where do I find it?

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I asked a similar question earlier but i don't understand what to do, I also have read other solutions like: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
I still don't know what to do, please help:

According to what I understand is that my `context = null;` and I am not sure why, and how to fix it...

I wrote a UniversImageLoader.class to be able to load images over several activities. Now I have initiated it in all my activities, but in my UIL class, I need to pass a context.

```
public class UniversalImageLoader {

    private static final int defaultImage = R.drawable.ic_android;
    private Context mContext;

    public UniversalImageLoader(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ImageLoaderConfiguration getConfig(){
        //File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(mContext);
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(mContext)//<--the error is in this line
                .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
                .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2) // default
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
                .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
                .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
                .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
                .diskCacheFileCount(100)
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
                .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(mContext)) // default
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
                .writeDebugLogs()
                .build();

        return config;
    }
```

in HomeActivity:[in every Activity I call it like this]

```
private void initImageLoader(){
        UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(mContext);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
    }
```

and in all those activities I call it in the OnCreate method like this:

```
initImageLoader();
```

So I have read up, looked at other solutions but can't find an understandable answer...your guidance will be highly appreciated!

Comment: just pass this as parameter instead of mContext in your activity . new UniversalImageLoader(this);

Comment: An error: UniversalImageLoader
(android.content.Context)
in UniversalImageLoader cannot be applied
to
the activity

Comment: Ok . if you are in the fragments  then you need to pass requireContext() instead.  new UniversalImageLoader(requireContext())

Comment: Wouldn't it be better (in this specific context) for him to use getApplicationContext() and convert the class into a singleton, considering the fact that it'll be used in multiple activities?

Comment: @darius f... thanks a lot just what I needed...

Comment: you're welcome Ben . just push up arrow to indicate it's was useful comment!

Comment: Do not repost questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.mContext = context;` in constructor so it will pass your context to the context of current class.

And pass `getApplicationContext` or `yourActivityName.this` where you are using this class.

If you are using it in fragment use `getActivity` or `getContext`.